# How to move caret position

Tags: javascript, extjs, element

This sounds super simple but I have had no luck in moving the cursor. I have tried many ways but this where I am at currently. I can provide more info if needed.

```
{
this.getMinute().addListener('spinup', this.SpinnerUp, this); //getMinute is the spinner field
}
...
timeSpinnerUp: function (field, e) {
el=this.getMinute().getEl();  // el.selection is not an option
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could HTMLInputElement.select() and/or HTMLInputElement.setSelectionRange() help you out?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange

Comment: I didn't see any documentation in Sencha's API Document with what you suggested . Though with your input, I stumbled across .selectText which allows me highlight the text or set the cursor.